# Sending whole Data Class instances in an argument

Tags: android, kotlin, arguments, instance, data-class

I'm really confused how to use a data class in an argument in an android.
I know how to implement a data class.
someone help me how to sending the data to the argument.

Comment: What have you tried? Here is some keyword for you: parcelable, bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use @Parcelize annotation and inherit your class from Parcelable, like this:

```
@Parcelize
data class MyData(val abc: Int, val xyz: String): Parcelable
```

Now in a "Add Argument" popup in the navigation editor, you should choose the "Custom parcelable" type of argument and it will be here.

Further actions depend on your approach to navigation between fragments. Personally, I do something like this (inside current fragment):

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.destinationFragmentId, DestinationFragmentArgs(myDataInstance).toBundle())
```

Comment: I clearly understand how to implement data class but can't understand hot to implement in the arguments.. please help me on it.

Comment: @PraveenMsp, ok, let's decide what arguments are we talking about. Do you mean fragment's arguments? Do you use Jetpack navigation? We need more information about your situation to answer.

Comment: yeah, I'm using jetpack navigation components and also the fragment's arguments.

Comment: Do you know how to add (any) arguments to the destination in nav graph? So is your issue that you can't find a way to add data class as an argument to destination, because there is no your data class in "argument type" dropdown list? Or you don't understand the entire flow?